# Shortcut for showing list of hashes "nicely"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I have a list of hashes, like the result of an `.attributes` call, what is a short way to create a line-by-line nicely readable output?
Like a shortcut for

```
u.attributes.each {|p| puts p[0].to_s + ": " + p[1].to_s}
```

Comment: I like to use `y hash` or `puts YAML.dump(hash)` that shows your hash in yaml.

Comment: You might like [`awesome_print`](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print). See also [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842546/best-way-to-pretty-print-a-hash).

Comment: I recommend `awesome_print` as well.

Comment: @oldergod I like your answer most, because it is just intended for a quick rails console inspection of what is there, and don't want to add a gem just for this. And `y` really is a nice way to achieve this, and as short as it can be :) I would mark it as the correct one if you want to post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS said in my comments, I like to use `y hash` or `puts YAML.dump(hash)` that shows your hash in yaml. [It can be used for other objects too](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/1405061475/viewing-a-model-in-yaml).

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
y h
#---
#:a: 1
#:b: 2
#:c: 3
# => nil
```

There is also [an informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572045/1004274) about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can make it much shorter unless you create your own method.

A minor enhancement would be:

```
u.attributes.each {|k,v| puts "#{k}: #{v}"}
```

Or you can create an extension to `Hash`:

```
class Hash
  def nice_print
    each {|k,v| puts "#{k}: #{v}"}
  end
end

u.attributes.nice_print
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an output for development purposes (in Rails log files for instance), `inspect` or `pretty_inspect` should do it :

```
u.attributes.inspect
```

or

```
u.attributes.pretty_inspect
```

But if what you are looking for is a way to print nicely in Rails console, I believe you will have to write your own method, or use a gem like **awesome_print**, see : [Ruby on Rails: pretty print for variable.hash_set.inspect ... is there a way to pretty print .inpsect in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597359/ruby-on-rails-pretty-print-for-variable-hash-set-inspect-is-there-a-way-to)

Answer (score 1):

[awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) is the way to go

`gem install awesome_print`

```
require "ap"
ap u.attributes
```