# How can I print each element of an array on its own line in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

When I run the Rails console, how can I display each item on its own line? Instead of

```
> Post.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "Post #0", comment: nil, link: "http://yahoo.com", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-30 02:29:28", updated_at: "2013-09-30 02:29:28">, #<Post id: 2, title: "Post #1", comment: nil,...
```

it would display as

```
> Post.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<Post id: 1, title: "Post #0", comment: nil, link: "http://yahoo.com", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-30 02:29:28", updated_at: "2013-09-30 02:29:28">, 
#<Post id: 2, title: "Post #1", comment: nil,...
```

Similar to `x` in Perl debugger. I tried

> Post.all.each{|e| e.inspect + "\n"}

But that only made it worse, and wasn't very convenient.

I saw [Ruby on Rails: pretty print for variable.hash_set.inspect ... is there a way to pretty print .inpsect in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597359/ruby-on-rails-pretty-print-for-variable-hash-set-inspect-is-there-a-way-to#6597570) and https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

but that doesn't seem to work

```
irb(main):005:0> require "awesome_print"
=> false
irb(main):006:0> ap Post.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "Post #0",
```

Comment: Note that ```Post.all``` doesn't return an array, but an ```ActiveRecord::Relation```. For a real ```Array``` you need ```#to_a```.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
Post.all.each {|e| puts e.inspect }
```

Thing to notice here is that `puts` function automatically adds a newline character after the statement, and if you instead use `print` it will function in a similar manner as `puts` without the newline character at the end.

---

If you are using awesome_print, try:

```
ap Post.all.to_a
```

---

Further, when you issue the first command, the output will be repeated at the end (as per your comment) to show the output of the current expression. You can suppress it by appending a <kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon) at the end of the command, like this:

```
Post.all.each { |e| puts e.inspect };
```

Comment: This works, but it repeats itself at the end without newlines all all one line. This is what it looks like: http://pastie.org/private/zy88frmnslbtpkvfowupxq

Comment: Thanks, `ap Post.all.to_a` worked! With colors no less!

Comment: The semicolon trick doesn't seem to work with Rails 4. It just seems to ignore the whole statement. But this works: `Post.all.each { |e| puts e.inspect };1` which prints a 1 at the end.

Comment: @Chloe: should work. The `semi-colon` will suppress the output of the whole expression/command. So, if your command explicitly prints something it will be printed even with the <kbd>;</kbd>. Try running: `puts "help"` vs `puts "help";` in your console.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
> puts Post.all.map(&:inspect).join("\n")
```